# Azure DevOps pipeline use yaml from another repo with dynamic branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two git repositories in Azure DevOps. In the first repository I have helper YAML files. In the second repository I have my application code and my main pipeline YAML.

I want the main pipeline YAML to utilise some of the helper YAML files in the first repo. I am currently doing this using

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: helperRepo
      type: git
      name: helper
      ref: 'refs/heads/develop'

stages:
  - stage: Setup
    jobs:
      - job: Setup
        steps:
        - template: dosetup.yaml@helperRepo
```

This approach works well. However, in the example above it is using the develop branch (as specified in the ref on the repository resource). I would like the ability for a developer to change the branch that is used in the helper repo when they queue the build.

I used the approach of having a branch name parameter as per: https://thomasthornton.cloud/2022/07/26/using-variables-to-dynamically-check-out-a-repository-using-a-specific-branch-or-tag-in-azure-devops-pipelines/

However, this produces an error message when queueing the build:

```
Could not get the latest source version for repository helper hosted on Azure Repos using ref refs/heads/$(branch_name)
```

Is it possible to do this? Or, it is just a limitation that the branch needs to be defined in the YAML rather than being dynamic?

Comment: You can choose the branch to use when queuing the pipeline under the "resources" section of the queue menu. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: That works and was rather obvious, not sure how I missed that! Thanks